# XDefaultDepth and XDisplayPlanes – what's the difference?

Tags: c, xlib

For `XDefaultDepth`, the **Xlib** documentation says:

> Returns the depth (number of planes) of the default root window for the
>   specified screen.
> Other depths may also be supported on this screen.

For `XDisplayPlanes`, it says:

> Returns the depth of the root window of the specified screen.

So basically, both return the depth of the desktop (the root window).
Both have the same number and types of parameters too. This is confusing :/
What is the difference between those two, then?
Because from this description they seem to do exactly the same :q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While they may be identical in implementation (see `grep root_depth /usr/include/X11/Xlib.h`), there is a semantic difference between "depth" and "planes",

- > The depth of a window or pixmap is the number of bits per pixel it
  >   has. The depth of a graphics context is the depth of the drawables it
  >   can be used in conjunction with graphicsoutput.
- > When a pixmap or window is thought of as a stack of [1-bit] bitmaps, each
  >   bitmap is called a plane or bit plane.

(from https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html)

And I think that is why they provided the separate interfaces.

Digging back into X11 history,

https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/Compaq-DEC/CRL-90-8.pdf

> Since backing store memory available for a window can be very
>   precious, particularly on a deep display, there are also window
>   attributes that inform the server which planes of the screen need to
>   be saved in backing store, along with a pixel value base so that the
>   window can be re-generated when exposed.

https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs349/f18/resources/X/TheXWindowSystem.pdf

> Overlay graphics can then be drawn by restricting output (see the next
>   section) to the single bit plane specified in the mask returned by the
>   color allocation. Turning bits in this plane on (to l’s) changes the
>   image to the fifth color, and turning them off reverts the image to
>   its original color.

There some Xlib functions like `XCopyPlane` that operate on a single
plane. If I was working with planes and wanted to know how many planes I had to work with, it would make more sense to call `XDisplayPlanes()` than `XDefaultDepth()`.

Comment: More fun reading: https://magcius.github.io/xplain/article/x-basics.html

Comment: The fact that they are both implemented the same way doesn't have to mean that they will *always* be implemented this way. When using an API, we shouldn't depend on its current implementation, because this can change. What matters is the **semantics** of these interfaces, and that's what I'm asking for (why two different functions and what's the supposed difference in their use). Thanks for the link to the sources, though. It's nice to be able to look how it works under the hood ;)

Comment: Hmm... The distinction between "depth" and "number of planes" is still unclear to me. Because in many places in the documentation they seem to be used interchangeably, as if "depth" were supposed to mean specifically "the number of planes". But thanks for the documents you provided, they seem to be more informative than the documentation, and shed some light to some other aspects of the APIs I had troubles with (e.g. Visuals).

Comment: Correct me if I got this wrong, but here's what I gathered from the materials you provided:
"Depth" concerns only the number of bit planes of the actual *pixel*, but the actual number of planes can be greater than that, to account for some additional planes, like overlays, backing store & stuff like that?

Comment: I suppose that pixel depth and number of planes *could* have been different, and that would have been covered by providing the different interfaces. But in practice they were just different ways of looking at the same data. I agree with your comment about semantics, and I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: The C wrappers `XDisplayPlanes` and `XDefaultDepth`
[just call the macros](https://github.com/mirror/libX11/blob/master/src/Macros.c),
and are there for language bindings. (moved from answer)